# Failed to display R script on the local OpenCPU single-user server

Tags: r, opencpu

I set up a local OpenCPU single-user server using RStudio. I also create my own R package(Package name: **test**) which includes only a simple test.R file. The source code is

```
f1 <- function(x, y) {x+y}
```

I started the OpenCPU server by typing `library(opencpu)` in RStudio's console. I got the following print.

```
Initiating OpenCPU server...
OpenCPU started.
[httpuv] http://localhost:6067/ocpu
OpenCPU single-user server ready.
```

I was able to run the script by typing `curl http://localhost:6067/ocpu/library/test/R/f1 -d "x=33&y=3"`.

But when I tried to display the R script(test.R) by typing `curl http://localhost:6067/ocpu/library/test/R/test.R`, it printed

`object 'test.R' not found`

`In call:
get(reqobject, paste("package", reqpackage, sep = ":"), inherits = FALSE)`

In addition, It's failed when I ran the test.R script by typing `curl http://localhost:6067/ocpu/library/test/R/test.R -X POST -d "x=3&y=4"`. Could I run the script like that?

Could anyone help with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install the R package, scripts under `/R` are turned into functions/objects. To read the source of the *function*, just do on of these:

```
curl http://localhost:6067/ocpu/library/test/R/f1/print
curl http://localhost:6067/ocpu/library/test/R/f1/ascii
```

Comment: thanks. After I typed `curl https://public.opencpu.org/ocpu/library/utils/R/read.csv -F "file=@mydata.csv"`, and I checked the source code of utils package, I didn't find any string of `read.csv`. Where is this object?

Comment: Can you move this conversation to the opencpu mailing list?

Comment: Ok. I'll move this to the mailing list.